# What does "in diminishing numbers" mean?

Tags: meaning

> While most snakes are concentrated in the southwest area, they have
>   extended north, east, and south **in diminishing numbers and varieties**.

What does "in diminishing numbers and varieties" exactly mean? Does it mean that "they have extended north, east, and south, and its numbers and varieties in those areas are diminishing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most snakes are concentrated in the south west area, but they have gone to other areas mentioned, but in fewer numbers, and there are fewer varieties than in the south west.